# Sorting text with some rules

Tags: java, sorting

I have a arraylist as follows

```
100 AAA 500-1 Lorem Ipsum
100 BBB 500-2 Lorem Ipsum
101 AAA 500-1 Lorem Ipsum
101 AAA 500-2 Lorem Ipsum
100 BBB 500-3 Lorem Ipsum
```

I want this to be sorted as

```
101 AAA 500-1 Lorem Ipsum
101 AAA 500-2 Lorem Ipsum
100 AAA 500-1 Lorem Ipsum
100 BBB 500-2 Lorem Ipsum
100 BBB 500-3 Lorem Ipsum
```

First, descending by number (101, 100).

Second, ascending by three letter word (AAA, BBB).

Third, ascending by third column (500-1, 500-2, 500-3)

I can split each element by space and get individual word and sort. But can anyone please help me with any other way or known algorithm?
Please let me know if you need more information.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm no Java developer, but there must be some "sort" functionality in your object, which you can probably override to sort on multiple conditions...

Comment: There's no specific algorithm for 'this'. Any kind of sorting will eventually practically boil down to quicksort, bubblesort or one of the other commonly accepted top algorithms. They all depend on a specific 'comparer' function though responsible for indicating the difference between 2 given values. All you need to do is override that.

Comment: You could create an Object for each row and make it implement `Comparable` and define the sorting in the `compareTo` method (or use a `Comparator` like Dworza suggests)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Creation of a [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) will solve your problem.
You should implement something like this:

```
public class MyComparator implements Comparator<MyObject> {    
  public int compare(MyObject o1, MyObject o2) {
    if (o1 == null || o2 == null) {
      throw new NullPointerException();
    }    
    if (o1.getValue1() != o2.getValue1()) {
      return Integer.compare(o1.getValue1(), o2.getValue1());
    }    
    return Integer.compare(o1.getValue2(), o2.getValue2());
  }
}
```

Of course there are more ways to solve this problem, e.g., you can implement your own sorting algorithm. However, I think that the use of `Comparator` is the right "***java-way***" to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you have a `Collection` of `String`.

I will be using Comparator to solve it.

```
    List<String> myCollection = new ArrayList<String>();

    Collections.sort(myCollection, new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            // splitting it with space character
            String[] split1 = o1.split(" ");
            String[] split2 = o2.split(" ");

            int i1 = Integer.parseInt(split1[0]);
            int i2 = Integer.parseInt(split2[0]);

            int diff = (i2 - i1);

            if(diff != 0){ // if two integer are equal
                return diff;
            }else{
                return split2[1].compareTo(split1[1]);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) for this, and pass it to the sort() method of the container.